# Joining power jack wire to charging port

Tags: wire

[image]
Do I need to weld the charging port to the wires of the broken power jack. Because this is not working. The LED of the power button just goes off and on occasionally with this. Is it necessary that I need to weld it to make it work?

Comment: You need to strip the wire much more neatly leaving enough bared wire to insert in the button terminals. Then you need to **solder** the wires in to ensure good connection. There should be a minimum of bare wire left and no danger of bare wires touching each other.

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow the instructions!

Answer (score 1):

In English, we solder wires in electronics.  Welding is used to join large pieces of steel.

Solder joints will be much more reliable than the joints in your picture, but greater care, and tighter twisting of the wires around the terminals, might make a somewhat reliable connection.

Comment: Thank you that really helped. I'll try  joining it again.

Comment: Also, thank you for the correction!